# unexpected indent raw_input on while

Tags: python, while-loop, indentation, raw-input

```
def teste():
  resp=raw_input("Quer fazer o teste: ")
  while resp=='s':
    dim=input("Qual o tamanho do tabuleiro: ")
    x=input("Qual a posicao x da peca: ")
    y=input("Qual a posicao y da peca: ")
    mov_sem_obst(x, y,dim)
    raw_input("Quer continuar? ")

teste()
```

This code should run the function mov_sem_obs every time when I answer s on resp but when I compile I have a problem with the identation of raw_input on the while.

Comment: First you need to assign `resp` to your raw_input. So `resp=raw_input("Quer continuar? ")`. Also, if you're having problems with indentation of that line, you need to check if you're using tabs or spaces and properly move that line into place.

Comment: Why are you using both input and raw_input? Do you have a reason for using the latter?

Comment: It worked tanks.

Comment: If you could accept my answer I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I was using input on both then I realised that input needs Quotation marks for beeing char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to assign resp to your `raw_input`. So `resp=raw_input("Quer continuar? ")`. Also, if you're having problems with indentation of that line, you need to check if you're using tabs or spaces and properly move that line into place